# How to append data to text files in the new line, ( \n does not work)

Tags: android, text, append, newline, store

I am using this code as a part to write data to a text file, but I am not sure how I can append the data to the new line. "\n" does not seem to be working. Here, variable "data" has this format: 
t=1, x=-3.1, y=19.0, z=-8.6
this part of the code iterates and the variable "data" is written each time; the current result is something like:
t=1, x=-6.9, y=-9.6, z=-6.9t=2, x=-1.4, y=6.2, z=7.0t=3, x=-1.4, y=6.1, z=6.9t=4, and so on, but what I would like is:

t=1, x=-6.9, y=-9.6, z=-6.9

t=2, x=-1.4, y=6.2, z=7.0

t=3, x=-1.4, y=6.1, z=6.9

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
        String datatest = data.toString();
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/test");
        directory.mkdirs();

        String filename = "test.txt";
        File file = new File(directory, filename);
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        try {
            osw.write(datatest + "\n");
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: `"\n" does not seem to be working`  How do you know?  How are you viewing the result?

Comment: I tested it on a real device and also used an app "ES file explorer" to see the actual result

Comment: Are you sure that you're reading the input *line by line*.

Comment: what do you mean by reading the input? Basically, this part of the code repeats and each time generates the variable "data" that has been created using this format: (long timestamp, double x, double y, double z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try "\r\n"

and to  make this answer longer :)

Comment: Actually, my code is working just fine. Also, I tried \r\n, it worked too! the problem was that I was checking the results using windows Notepad, and I am not sure why Note does not show the results correctly. I tried changing the file from txt to csv and now I can see that the data are appended to the new lines! Thanks everyone!

Comment: @kaman Windows will only perceive \r\n as newline, it is a legacy issue with windows not any problem with your code